# Fetch details from arrays in mongodb

Tags: arrays, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have imported details about a YouTube Channel to mongodb and i am trying to get the details of YouTube Channels Video.
Say I am trying to get the "VideoDetail"-> Video_Id -> Video_Name -> Like_Count
Here "VideoDetail" is Array and there are multiple Objects like- 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,.....
under each Object - 0 -> there is the details of each Video.

I tried Using the following code, which did not fetch the details.

```
=> 
db.Ammu.find({_id:ObjectId('64874529be6740b5c6f5961f')} , {"VideoDetail.0.Video_Id" : 1 , VideoDetail.0.Video_Name" : 1 , VideoDetail.0.Like_Count" : 1})
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$elemMatch` in combination with the `$` positional operatior in a projection to only output the object from the `VideoDetail` array that matches your condition.

For example, to get the first object from the `VideoDetail` array you can query the `Video_Id` property like so:

```js
db.Ammu.find({
    _id: ObjectId('64874529be6740b5c6f5961f'),
    VideoDetail: {
        $elemMatch:{
            Video_Id: 'MxxnwmBUp-0'
        }
    }
},{
    'VideoDetail.Video_Id.$': 1,
    'VideoDetail.Video_Name.$': 1,
    'VideoDetail.Like_Count.$': 1
});
```